# SQL: Compare two tables on part of entry without INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join

I am trying to select all entries of table A that meet some conditions of table B.

In table A I have species samples with the columns d**ate, site, sample_id** (combination of site and date) and **taxon**.

In table B I have environmental data samples with the columns **date, site, sample_id**.

I want to get all species samples of table A where environmental samples (table B) were taken at the same site and in the year 2005. 
However, the date column is formatted yyyy-mm-dd and not yyyy.

I tried the following code:

```
SELECT tableA.site AS Asite, tableB.site AS Bsite, tableA.date AS Adate, tableB.date AS Bdate, tableA.taxon
FROM tableA
INNER JOIN tableB
ON Asite = Bsite
WHERE (Adate BETWEEN '2005-01-01' AND '2005-12-31')
AND (Bdate BETWEEN '2005-01-01' AND '2005-12-31')
```

This resulted in a table with all combinations of different sampling dates within the year 2005 that where sampled at the same site. The taxon entries were listed multiple times. I got a table like this:

**Asite | Bsite | Adate | Bdate | taxon**

```
BY | BY | 2005-07-17 | 2005-03-22 | Navicula antonii
BY | BY | 2005-07-16 | 2005-03-22 | Navicula antonii
BY | BY | 2005-07-17 | 2005-04-19 | Navicula antonii
BY | BY | 2005-07-16 | 2005-04-19 | Navicula antonii
```

However, I don't want the species sampled on one date being listed twice. The table should look like this:

```
**Asite | Bsite | Adate | Bdate | taxon**
BY | BY | 2005-07-17 | 2005-03-22 | Navicula antonii
BY | BY | 2005-07-16 | 2005-03-22 | Navicula antonii
```

I hope I could somehow explain my problem and would be very thankful if anyone knows a solution.

Maybe I should approach this problem on a different way and somehow also INNER JOIN on the year from the date column...

Comment: can you show us a sample of actual output and the output you desire?

Comment: Add sample table data and the expected result, as formatted text (not images.)

Comment: I just edited my question to include this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want only one row per row in "A".  If so, aggregation or `distinct on` may be what you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (a.site, a.date, a.taxon) a.site AS Asite, b.site AS Bsite, a.date AS Adate, b.date AS Bdate, a.taxon
FROM tableA a INNER JOIN
     tableB b
     ON a.Asite =b. Bsite
WHERE a.Adate BETWEEN '2005-01-01' AND '2005-12-31' AND
      b.Bdate BETWEEN '2005-01-01' AND '2005-12-31'
ORDER BY a.site, a.date, a.taxon, b.date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `INTERSECT`:

```
SELECT site, date
  FROM tableA
INTERSECT
SELECT site, date
  FROM tableB
 WHERE ( date BETWEEN '2005-01-01' AND '2005-12-31' );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I think you want:

```
create table species_sample
(
    sample_date      date,
    site             varchar(32),
    taxon            Varchar(32)
);

create table environmental_sample
(
    sample_date      date,
    site             varchar(32)
);

insert into species_sample (sample_date, site, taxon) values ('2005-07-17', 'BY', 'Navicula antonii');
insert into species_sample (sample_date, site, taxon) values ('2005-07-17', 'CZ', 'Navicula abiskoensis');
insert into species_sample (sample_date, site, taxon) values ('2005-07-17', 'AX', 'Navicula abscondita');

insert into environmental_sample (sample_date, site) values ('2005-04-19', 'BY');
insert into environmental_sample (sample_date, site) values ('2006-04-19', 'CZ');


# select * from species_sample;
 sample_date | site |        taxon         
-------------+------+----------------------
 2005-07-17  | BY   | Navicula antonii
 2005-07-17  | CZ   | Navicula abiskoensis
 2005-07-17  | AX   | Navicula abscondita
(3 rows)

# select * from environmental_sample;
 sample_date | site 
-------------+------
 2005-04-19  | BY
 2006-04-19  | CZ
(2 rows)

select 
    site,
    sample_date,
    taxon
from
    species_sample
where
    site in
    (
        select site 
        from environmental_sample
        where extract('year' from sample_date) = 2005
);
```

Result:

```
 site | sample_date |      taxon       
------+-------------+------------------
 BY   | 2005-07-17  | Navicula antonii
(1 row)
```

Note the "extract" to get the year from the date.

The site must be the same in both tables so there's no need to list the column twice in the result set.

Do you want the date from the environmental_sample table?  If so, which one?  The earliest?  If you do want a date from the environmental_sample table, let me know and I'll give you a modified query.